# Unable to get Django object via primary key

Tags: python, django

I have an AJAX function that calls another function as such.

```
def update_votes(song_pk):
    song = Song.objects.get(pk=song_pk)
    song.votes += 1
    song.save()

@dajaxice_register
def update_disable(request, song_pk):
    update_votes(song_pk)
    dajax = Dajax()
    dajax.assign('.vote', 'disabled', 'disabled')
    return dajax.json()
```

The button disabling part works fine when used alone. But when I use the `update_votes()` function in the `update_disable()` function nothing works. The problem is with the `song = Song.objects.get(pk=song_pk)` line. What am I doing wrong?

This is how I am getting the primary key.

```
function update(){
    Dajaxice.hunt.update_disable(Dajax.process,{'song_pk':$('.song_pk').val()})
}
```

This is my HTML

```
{% for song in dj_song_list %}
        <div>
            <p><h3>{{ song.name }}</h3></p>
            <p style="display:none;" class="song_pk">{{ song.id }}</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-custom" class='vote' onclick="update();">Vote as Favourite</button>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: A tad more info please... any errors?

Comment: The button disabling part works fine when used alone. But when I use the `update_votes()` function in the `update_disable()` function nothing works.

Comment: This is now the third time you have asked the same question. Please stop asking duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This selector `$('.song_pk')` will select **all** of the elements with the .song_pk class in the page. The `.val()` will return the value of the first item in the selected elements, which is usually the top most one.

Secondly, instead of putting the pk in a hidden p tag, you probably want to put it into a hidden input tag instead. If you really want to put it into a p tag, you'll want to use `.text()` instead of `.val()`.

Comment: How can I get the value of the `{{ song.id }}` associated with button I click?

Comment: @JaskaranRana: .val() works for form input elements, not p tags.

Comment: You can pass `this` like so: `onclick="update(this);"` and then inside you can pass the passed `this` with jquery to get the selector only for that element. However, you might want to attach your event handlers using jQuery/unobtrusive JavaScript instead of doing what you're currently doing.

Comment: I'm using `onclick="update(this);"` and then in the JavaScript `console.log($('.song_pk').text(this));`. But this seems to be printing `p.song.pk` multiple times. What would be the correct syntax for this?